# Codeigniter send GET parameter with site_url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this part of code in my view file:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post['content']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/blog/show'); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Well .. how to send GET parameter with `site_url` function, this is my anchor part:

```
a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/blog/show'); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
```

where to send `$post['id']` ?

I see some question in SO, but answers was with hardcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should be like this :**

```
<a href="<?=site_url('admin/blog/show/'.$post['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
```

The given code should be like this :

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$post['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$post['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$post['content']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="<?=site_url('admin/blog/show/'.$post['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

In your `show` method access `post id` like this :

```
public function show($post_id)
{
  echo $post_id;
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 2):

here we have a example

```
echo anchor('news/local/'. $post['id'], 'any text', array('title' => 'The best news!'));
```

In your controller you will get something like.

```
echo $this->uri->segment('3');
```

Also load url helper/library as well.

Comment: Thank u, u help me to learn more about anchor function and uri->segment!